# How to get the entered value other than those listed from primefaces SelectCheckboxMenu component?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

For example, those listed Scarface - Goodfellas and The Godfather. However, user input matrix.

How can I get it?

Comment: It has a filter,no 'open input', so you can't

Comment: @Kukeltje It's too bad :(

Comment: Sorry, it should have been an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a filter,no 'open input', so you can't